# How do I pass in a multidimensional int array into a function in C?

Tags: c

As above, say I have a 3 dimensional array, a[][][], and I want to pass this to a function; how should I declare the function parameter?

Comment: havent used c for ages.... pass the pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void function1(int array[][3][4])
{
    ...use array here...
}

void function2(void)
{
    int array[20][3][4];
    ...load array...
    function1(array);
}
```

Comment: +1: Assuming the OP really does have an `int [][][]`, this is *the* correct answer.

Comment: we need to add in a fixed dimensions for the latter dimensions?

Comment: @nubela: yes, pretty much.  If you've got a C99 compiler, you can read up on VLA (variable length arrays) which allow you to change dimensions at runtime; I think that allows you to specify all the dimensions dynamically, but you have to pass the numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Just declare a triple pointer

```
int functionName(int*** arrayPtr, int x, int y, int z){
  return arrayPtr[z][y][x];
}
```

Comment: a multi dimensional array is not the same thing as triply-indirect pointers

Comment: Since an array is represented by a variable that is associated with the address of its first storage location. A pointer is also the address of a storage location with a defined type, so ANSI-C permits the use of the array [ ] index notation with both pointer variables and array variables. Single dimension = 1 pointer, Two Dimension == two pointers, three dimensions = 3 pointers.

Comment: This is only true for one "level" of array/pointer; arrays do not decay to pointers recursively.

Comment: @Oli You are right. For the others under the same impression I was here is a link that gives great explanations of the problem with dereferncing multiple times for a declared multi-dimensional array: [link](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/append-c.html)

Answer (score -1):

I would send a pointer to pointer to pointer with all dimensions.

```
void foo(int ***ar, size_t l, size_t m, size_t n)
{ /* ... */ }
```

Comment: @Oil You're right, here is more on that for others: http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/append-c.html